# How can I have a delayed (with Undo) Swipe to Delete Recyclerview that uses Room and LiveData?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-livedata

I implemented a swipe-to-delete feature in my app using the following sample as a guide [nemanja-kovacevic/recycler-view-swipe-to-delete](https://github.com/nemanja-kovacevic/recycler-view-swipe-to-delete). Initially I was using a simple SQLite Database class and everything was working correctly.

In attempting to update my app to utilize Android's Architecture Components Room and LiveData, I followed Google's [Room with a view Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/). After updating the code, it seemed to work, and does for a single swipe. However, if you swipe another row before the Undo delay completes, LiveData updates the adapter's cached copy of the List so that the subsequent pending removal runnables can't find the item they are supposed to move in the list (position=-1), which crashes the app.

That was a lot of explanation, here is the Adapter Code:

```java
    public class DropsListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DropsListAdapter.DropHolder> {
    private final static int PENDING_REMOVAL_TIMEOUT = 3000; // 3sec
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private HashMap<DeadDrop, Runnable> pendingRunnables = new HashMap<>();
    private List<DeadDrop> deadDrops;
    private List<DeadDrop> dropsPendingRemoval;

    DropsListAdapter(Context context) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.dropsPendingRemoval = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DropHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new DropHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.drop_list_item, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DropHolder holder, int position) {
        final DeadDrop deadDrop = deadDrops.get(position);
        if (dropsPendingRemoval.contains(deadDrop)) {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            holder.undoIt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.rowWrapper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.rowWrapper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.latitude.setText(Converts.latitudeToSexaString(deadDrop.getLatitude()));
            holder.longitude.setText(Converts.longitudeToSexaString(deadDrop.getLongitude()));
            holder.undoIt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (deadDrops != null)
            return deadDrops.size();
        else return 0;
    }

    void pendingRemoval(int position) {
        final DeadDrop mDeadDrop = deadDrops.get(position);
        if (!dropsPendingRemoval.contains(mDeadDrop)) {
            dropsPendingRemoval.add(mDeadDrop);
            notifyItemChanged(position);
            Runnable pendingRemovalRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Here is the problem. After the first item is removed,
                    // the next drop to remove is not found in the newly updated
                    // list of items (deadDrops).
                    int pos = deadDrops.indexOf(mDeadDrop);
                    remove(pos);
                }
            };
            mHandler.postDelayed(pendingRemovalRunnable, PENDING_REMOVAL_TIMEOUT);
            pendingRunnables.put(mDeadDrop, pendingRemovalRunnable);
        }
    }

    void setDeadDrops(List<DeadDrop> drops) {
        deadDrops = drops;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void remove(int position) {
        DeadDrop drop = deadDrops.get(position);
        dropsPendingRemoval.remove(drop);
        if (deadDrops.contains(drop)) {
            deadDrops.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            ((DeadDropActivity) context).mDeadDropViewModel.delete(drop);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    boolean isPendingRemoval(int position) {
        return dropsPendingRemoval.contains(deadDrops.get(position));
    }

    /**
     * Drops List View Holder class
     */
    protected class DropHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        LinearLayout rowWrapper;
        TextView latitude, longitude;
        ImageButton mapIt;
        Button undoIt;

        DropHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            rowWrapper = itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_wrapper);
            latitude = itemView.findViewById(R.id.latitude_sexagesimal);
            longitude = itemView.findViewById(R.id.longitude_sexagesimal);
            mapIt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_map_it);
            undoIt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.undo_button);
            mapIt.setOnClickListener(this);
            undoIt.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.button_map_it) {

                String gUri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH,
                        "https://www.google.com/maps/@%f,%f," + DeadDropActivity.GMAPS_CLOSE_ZOOM + "z",
                        deadDrops.get(getLayoutPosition()).getLatitude(),
                        deadDrops.get(getLayoutPosition()).getLongitude());

                Intent gIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(gUri));
                gIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps",
                        "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");

                try {
                    context.startActivity(gIntent);

                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    try {
                        String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f?z=25",
                                deadDrops.get(getLayoutPosition()).getLatitude(),
                                deadDrops.get(getLayoutPosition()).getLongitude());
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
                        context.startActivity(intent);

                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException innerEx) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Please install a maps application or browser.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        innerEx.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                Toast.makeText(context, "Map Button clicked at " + getLayoutPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (v.getId() == R.id.undo_button) {
                DeadDrop deadDrop = deadDrops.get(getLayoutPosition());
                // user wants to undo the removal, let's cancel the pending task
                // Cancelling still works without issue.
                Runnable pendingRemovalRunnable = pendingRunnables.get(deadDrop);
                pendingRunnables.remove(deadDrop);
                if (pendingRemovalRunnable != null)
                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(pendingRemovalRunnable);
                dropsPendingRemoval.remove(deadDrop);
                // this will rebind the row in "normal" state
                notifyItemChanged(deadDrops.indexOf(deadDrop));
                Log.d(TAG, TAG_CLASS + ".onClickUndo(" + getLayoutPosition() + ")");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Utility class
     */
    public static class Converts {

        static String latitudeToSexaString(double latitude) {
            String latDir = (latitude < 0) ? "S" : "N";
            double lat = Math.abs(latitude);
            double s;
            int d, m;

            d = (int) lat;
            m = (int) ((lat - d) * 60);
            s = (((lat - d) * 60) - m) * 60;

            return String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%02d\u00B0", d) +
                    String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%02d\u0027", m) +
                    String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%02.1f\"", s) + latDir;
        }

        static String longitudeToSexaString(double longitude) {
            String lonDir = (longitude < 0) ? "W" : "E";
            double lon = Math.abs(longitude);
            double s;
            int d, m;

            d = (int) lon;
            m = (int) ((lon - d) * 60);
            s = (((lon - d) * 60) - m) * 60;

            return String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%02d\u00B0", d) +
                    String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%02d\u0027", m) +
                    String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%02.1f\"", s) + lonDir;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the logcat where it shows that the indexof is returning -1 because the instance is not found, but that is because it is a new instance of the same object (The ID is the same, but the object.toString() is different:

```
2019-07-14 02:29:17.890 18618-18618/com.daweber.deaddrop D/daweber.DD: .DropListAdapter.pendingRemoval(): 2
2019-07-14 02:29:17.890 18618-18618/com.daweber.deaddrop D/daweber.DD: .DropListAdapter.pendingRemoval(): {}
2019-07-14 02:29:17.890 18618-18618/com.daweber.deaddrop D/daweber.DD: .DropListAdapter.pendingRemoval(): ID|16
2019-07-14 02:29:20.896 18618-18618/com.daweber.deaddrop D/daweber.DD: .DropListAdapter.[Runnable]run(): 2
    DropID = com.daweber.deaddrop.DeadDrop@d769128(ID|16)
    DropsList = [com.daweber.deaddrop.DeadDrop@50eec1a, com.daweber.deaddrop.DeadDrop@966a34b, com.daweber.deaddrop.DeadDrop@d769128]
2019-07-14 02:29:20.992 18618-18618/com.daweber.deaddrop D/daweber.DD: .DeadDropActivity.[Observer].onChanged(): [com.daweber.deaddrop.DeadDrop@9f16479, com.daweber.deaddrop.DeadDrop@6fad5be]
2019-07-14 02:29:37.286 18618-18618/com.daweber.deaddrop D/daweber.DD: .DropListAdapter.pendingRemoval(): 1
2019-07-14 02:29:37.287 18618-18618/com.daweber.deaddrop D/daweber.DD: .DropListAdapter.pendingRemoval(): {com.daweber.deaddrop.DeadDrop@d769128=com.daweber.deaddrop.DropsListAdapter$1@38e0d6c}
2019-07-14 02:29:37.287 18618-18618/com.daweber.deaddrop D/daweber.DD: .DropListAdapter.pendingRemoval(): ID|15
2019-07-14 02:29:37.766 18618-18618/com.daweber.deaddrop D/daweber.DD: .DropListAdapter.pendingRemoval(): 0
2019-07-14 02:29:37.766 18618-18618/com.daweber.deaddrop D/daweber.DD: .DropListAdapter.pendingRemoval(): {com.daweber.deaddrop.DeadDrop@6fad5be=com.daweber.deaddrop.DropsListAdapter$1@4049458, com.daweber.deaddrop.DeadDrop@d769128=com.daweber.deaddrop.DropsListAdapter$1@38e0d6c}
2019-07-14 02:29:37.767 18618-18618/com.daweber.deaddrop D/daweber.DD: .DropListAdapter.pendingRemoval(): ID|4
2019-07-14 02:29:40.292 18618-18618/com.daweber.deaddrop D/daweber.DD: .DropListAdapter.[Runnable]run(): 1
    DropID = com.daweber.deaddrop.DeadDrop@6fad5be(ID|15)
    DropsList = [com.daweber.deaddrop.DeadDrop@9f16479, com.daweber.deaddrop.DeadDrop@6fad5be]
2019-07-14 02:29:40.358 18618-18618/com.daweber.deaddrop D/daweber.DD: .DeadDropActivity.[Observer].onChanged(): [com.daweber.deaddrop.DeadDrop@c9d4e22]
2019-07-14 02:29:40.769 18618-18618/com.daweber.deaddrop D/daweber.DD: .DropListAdapter.[Runnable]run(): -1
    DropID = com.daweber.deaddrop.DeadDrop@9f16479(ID|4)
    DropsList = [com.daweber.deaddrop.DeadDrop@c9d4e22]
2019-07-14 02:30:02.153 18766-18766/com.daweber.deaddrop D/daweber.DD: .DeadDropActivity.[Observer].onChanged(): [com.daweber.deaddrop.DeadDrop@ff36b61]
```

So, the question now becomes, how do I modify this line

```
int pos = deadDrops.indexOf(mDeadDrop);
```

to get the index of the object by looking up the object.getId() instead of the object signature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have found a "brute force" way to do this and it seems to prevent crashing, but if the list grew to 1000s of entries, this might not be the most efficient way, so if anyone has a better solution:

**new run()**

```
@Override
                public void run() {
                    final String TAG_FUN = ".[Runnable]run(): ";
                    // TODO: Here is the problem.
                    for (int i = 0; i <= deadDrops.size(); i++) {
                        DeadDrop d = deadDrops.get(i);
                        if (d.getId() == mDeadDrop.getId()) {
                            int pos = deadDrops.indexOf(d);
                            Log.d(TAG, TAG_CLS + TAG_FUN + pos
                                    + "\nDropID = " + d.toString() + "(ID|" + d.getId() + ")"
                                    + "\nDropsList = " + deadDrops.toString());
                            remove(pos);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
```